# Binding a Typeclass with Scala-Guice

Tags: scala, guice

I hope I am on the right track.

I have an SBT subproject (`model`) that defines an abstract class `AbstractTrainingEntity` and several subclasses (`Lecture`, `Section`, etc.) Another SBT subproject (`cadenza`) `dependsOn` the first SBT subproject.

The `model` subproject defines an abstract typeclass with two method signatures that will be implemented in the `cadenza` subproject. This is intended to allow code in the `model` subproject to reference methods that are not defined until the two SBT subprojects are linked together:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class AbstractTranscodeDispatch[A: TypeTag](dispatchType: AbstractTrainingEntity) {
  def transcodeUrl(trainingEntity: AbstractTrainingEntity): String
  def uploadUrl(trainingEntity: AbstractTrainingEntity): String
}
```

The `cadenza` subproject wires it together in a `Scala-Guice` module:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

class CadenzaModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  @Provides
  def provideTranscodeDispatch[T: TypeTag](dispatchType: AbstractTrainingEntity) = new TranscodeDispatch[T](dispatchType)
}
```

This gives an error:

```
[error] /var/work/training/cadenza/modules/cadenza/app/modules/cadenza/CadenzaModule.scala:53: javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeTag does not take type parameters
[error]   def provideTranscodeDispatch[T: TypeTag](dispatchType: AbstractTrainingEntity) = new TranscodeDispatch[T](dispatchType)
```

Elsewhere in the `cadenza` subproject there is an implementation

```
class TranscodeDispatch[A: TypeTag](dispatchType: AbstractTrainingEntity) 
extends AbstractTranscodeDispatch[A](dispatchType)
```

Do I need to use a `TypeLiteral` somehow? I am going about this all wrong? The docs are thin.